# How to create signature capture for android application

Tags: java, android, digital-signature

right now i am currently engaged in a project that requires building an application for logistic. I am stuck at a point where i had to create a signature capture function where the user could sign on the application and the signature would be stored as a image file. I do not know what i should do to get started on this function. Some help would be appreciated